# When are minimal faithful modules over algebras unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, graded-modules, superalgebra

Let $A$ be a unital associative algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. We say an $A$-module $V$ is "minimal faithful" if (i) $V$ is faithful and (ii) $V$ does not have a proper submodule that is faithful.

First of all, does a faithful $A$-module exist? If so, is it finite-dimensional / finitely-generated? What conditions must $A$ satisfy such that these are true?

Is a minimal faithful module of $A$ unique up to isomorphism? If not, what are some necessary and sufficient conditions on $A$ such that uniqueness holds? For example, is it enough to assume that $A$ is semisimple and Frobenius?

Bonus: Let $A$ and $V$ be graded by an abelian group. (For example, consider supermodules over superalgebras). How do the answers to the above questions change?

Comment: Do you mean a unital associative algebra by "algebra" ?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit the question to include these assumptions.

Comment: The Lie algebra case is also interesting.

Comment: @AlexTurzillo What do you mean "semisimple and Frobenius"?  If you mean "semisimple Artinian," then it's redundant because semisimple Artinian rings are Frobenius. If you mean "Jacobson radical zero" then it's convoluted because a Frobenius ring with Jacobson radical zero is semisimple Artinian.  Or maybe you meant "or" and not "and"?

Comment: @AlexTurzillo Also, over five questions in a single post without work of your own is definitely not going to go over well in the long run. It would be better to ask a more focused question and mention what your thoughts have been so far.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $A$ has a faithful module. To see this, note that since $1\in A$ satisfies $1a=a$, the left regular module $_AA$ is faithful (and finitely generated by $1\in A$).

If $A_0={_AA}$ is not minimal, then it contains a proper submodule $A_1$ which is still faithful. Repeating, you can get a descending chain of faithful $A$-modules
$$A_0\supset A_1\supset\cdots$$
If you impose the descending chain condition on $A$ (i.e. make $A$ artinian) then you can find a minimal one. There is no reason why this minimal one needs to be unique, though.

In the case of graded algebras, nothing changes except for the fact that you require everything to be graded...

As for the question about whether a faithful representation needs to be finite dimensional, the answer is no. Take the Heisenberg algebra $H$ which is the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra generated by elements $x,d$ satisfying $dx-xd=1$. A minimal faithful representation of this algebra comes from its action on the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[X]$, where $x.p(X)=Xp(X)$ and $d.p(x)=\frac{d}{dx}p(x)$. This representation is infinite dimensional.

Comment: How do I know that $A_n$ does not contain two non-isomorphic faithful $A$-modules $A_{n+1}$ and $A_{n+1}^'$ as proper submodules?

Comment: I just edited to note that there is no reason to expect uniqueness of a minimal faithful representation. In fact, there are counterexamples.

Comment: OK. I'd be interested in hearing your counterexample if you have one in mind. I'm also still curious whether something stronger than the DCC gives us uniqueness.

Comment: I'm doubtful there is a meaningful condition you could impose. Also, I'd have to think a bit about a counterexample. The examples that come to mind are for faithful representations of groups or Lie algebras (which is a slightly different use of the term "faithful").

Comment: The first Weyl algebra $H$ (or Heisenberg algebra, as @David Hill calls it) has infinitely many non-isomorphic simple modules. Since $H$ is a simple ring, they are all faithful. In the same vain, but easier, examples appear for simple PIDs. E.g. the Ore extension $B=B_1(\mathbb C) = \mathbb C(X)[Y;\delta]$ with $\delta(Y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial X}$ is a PID due to existence of a Euclidean division algorithm. It's then not so hard to find two irreducibles elements $f$ and $g$ of $B$ with $B/fB \ncong B/gB$. (These are however non-Artinian rings.)